# Applying onchange event on multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in implementing onchange event on multiple select elements. Everytime the select element changes, it is not producing the desired result. Below is the code:

```js
/**Javascript:**/

 var selectedOptions = [];

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var selectElements = ["question1","question2","question3"];
  initSelectChangeListener(selectElements);
 });

 function initSelectChangeListener(elementids){
  for(a = 0; a < elementids.length; a++){
   var element = document.getElementById(elementids[a]);
   element.onchange = function(){ onOptionSelected(element) };
   console.log(element.id + " onchange listener is applied...");
  }
 }

 function onOptionSelected(element){
  console.log("---------------------------");
  console.log("Element : " + element.id);
  console.log("Index : " + element.options.selectedIndex);
  var option = element.options[element.options.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log("Selected Option : " + option);
  console.log("---------------------------");
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <br/>
 Security Question 1 : 
 <select id="question1" name="question1">
  <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
  <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
 </select>
 <br/><br/>
 Security Question 2 : 
 <select id="question2" name="question2">
  <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
  <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
 </select>
 <br/><br/>
 Security Question 3 : 
 <select id="question3" name="question3">
  <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
  <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
 </select>
```

Even though I selected the 1st and 2nd element, it always points out the 3rd element. Please see the attached image for the output.[Please see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpa1a.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is all about the scope. `{...}` does not have it's own scope in JavaScript. So when the loop finishes *a* holds only the last value of the iteration.

Declare the variable *a* with the keyword [*let*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). This will create a individual scope for the variable inside the loop.

Change

```
for(a = 0; a < elementids.length; a++){
```

To

```
for(let a = 0; a < elementids.length; a++){
```

```js
var selectedOptions = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var selectElements = ["question1","question2","question3"];
    initSelectChangeListener(selectElements);
});

function initSelectChangeListener(elementids){
    for(let a = 0; a < elementids.length; a++){
        var element = document.getElementById(elementids[a]);
        element.onchange = function(){ onOptionSelected(element) };
        console.log(element.id + " onchange listener is applied...");
    }
}

function onOptionSelected(element){
    console.log("---------------------------");
    console.log("Element : " + element.id);
    console.log("Index : " + element.options.selectedIndex);
    var option = element.options[element.options.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log("Selected Option : " + option);
    console.log("---------------------------");
}
```

```html
Security Question 1 : 
<select id="question1" name="question1">
    <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
    <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
Security Question 2 : 
<select id="question2" name="question2">
    <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
    <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
Security Question 3 : 
<select id="question3" name="question3">
    <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
    <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
</select>
```

**IE:** If you are using *IE* then use `(function(){})()` syntax. This will work in all browser.

```js
var selectedOptions = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var selectElements = ["question1","question2","question3"];
    initSelectChangeListener(selectElements);
});

function initSelectChangeListener(elementids){
    for(let a = 0; a < elementids.length; a++){
      (function(b){
        var element = document.getElementById(elementids[b]);
        element.onchange = function(){ onOptionSelected(element) };
        console.log(element.id + " onchange listener is applied...");
      })(a);
    }
}

function onOptionSelected(element){
    console.log("---------------------------");
    console.log("Element : " + element.id);
    console.log("Index : " + element.options.selectedIndex);
    var option = element.options[element.options.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log("Selected Option : " + option);
    console.log("---------------------------");
}
```

```html
Security Question 1 : 
<select id="question1" name="question1">
    <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
    <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
Security Question 2 : 
<select id="question2" name="question2">
    <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
    <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
Security Question 3 : 
<select id="question3" name="question3">
    <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
    <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
    <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate it but I tried your code in IE but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there's a problem with the variable `element` that is declared as global within a function.

There are two solutions for that:

Make the variable local using `let`:

```
function initSelectChangeListener(elementids) {
  for (a = 0; a < elementids.length; a++) {
    let element = document.getElementById(elementids[a]);
    element.onchange = function() {
      onOptionSelected(element)
    };
    console.log(element.id + " onchange listener is applied...");
  }
}
```

Use `this` in the `onchange` function that is applied to `element`:

```
 function initSelectChangeListener(elementids) {
   for (a = 0; a < elementids.length; a++) {
     var element = document.getElementById(elementids[a]);
     element.onchange = function() {
       onOptionSelected(this)
     };
     console.log(element.id + " onchange listener is applied...");
   }
 }
```

```js
var selectedOptions = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var selectElements = ["question1", "question2", "question3"];
  initSelectChangeListener(selectElements);
});

function initSelectChangeListener(elementids) {
  for (a = 0; a < elementids.length; a++) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementids[a]);
    element.onchange = function() {
      onOptionSelected(this)
    };
    console.log(element.id + " onchange listener is applied...");
  }
}

function onOptionSelected(element) {
  console.log("---------------------------");
  console.log("Element : " + element.id);
  console.log("Index : " + element.options.selectedIndex);
  var option = element.options[element.options.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log("Selected Option : " + option);
  console.log("---------------------------");
}
```

```html
Security Question 1 :
<select id="question1" name="question1">
  <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
  <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
</select>
<br/><br/> Security Question 2 :
<select id="question2" name="question2">
  <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
  <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
</select>
<br/><br/> Security Question 3 :
<select id="question3" name="question3">
  <option value="What is your favorite color?">What is your favorite color?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your school in elementary?">What is the name of your school in elementary?</option>
  <option value="What is the name of your fist pet?">What is the name of your fist pet?</option>
  <option value="Who is your first love?">Who is your first love?</option>
</select>
```